# Recommended pattern to confirm action in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

Sorry for this question, but today I feel short of ideas. What I need is a good way to implement confirmation of requests in spring mvc. suppose I have

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=deleteitem")
public ModelAndView deleteItem(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id){

 ...
}
```

I'd like something that I could re-use, like a confirmation page with a parametric message, that then recalls this. I can think of 100 of ways, but none seems clean and elegant. So I'd like a word from who has more experience than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using something like below using [jQuery overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html) and defined `modalyesno` jsp tag.

Delete button - in `rev` attribute i provide `delete action`, that will be requested as user confirm deletion (clicks yes). One `<t:modalyesno />` component may work for many Delete buttons.

```
<a href="#" class="modalInput" rev="deleteitem.html?id=123" rel="#yesno" >Delete</a>
<t:modalyesno id="yesno">
    Deleting item. Are You sure ?
</t:modalyesno>
```

modalyesno.tag:

```
<%@ tag description="Confirmation Dialog" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ attribute name="id" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<!-- confirm modal dialog -->   
<div class="modal" id="${id}">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <jsp:doBody/>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
        <a class="close" href="#"><span>No</span></a>   
        <a class="close yes" href="#"><span>Yes</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".modalInput").overlay({
            mask: {
                color: '#aaa',
                loadSpeed: 'fast',
                opacity: 0.5
            },
            speed: 'fast',
            closeOnClick: true
      });
      $('.modalInput').click(function(){
          var modal = $(this).attr('rel');
          var action = $(this).attr('rev');
          /* set action on yes button */              
          $(modal).find('.yes').eq(0).attr('href', action);
      });
});
```

Comment: My problem with this solution is that it violates standards.  You should never use a GET operation to modify data.  Imagine a GoogleBot crawling your site.  It doesn't know the difference between the YES and NO links, and could purge your entire database.

I urge you to find a manner that POSTS or DELETES the web resource so an innocent bot will avoid those method, and your app conforms to well established standards.

Comment: @Eddie It must be a serious security hole in your system then. If a bot can damage your system, anyone can.

Comment: Haha, yes @vic, reading my last comment my use case was definitely a bit extreme, but my opinion on adhering standards remains. Create=post, read=get, update=put, delete=delete.